# Horizontal scrollview crashes

Tags: java, android, crash, scrollview

I need to show several images on the screen, allowing users to swipe in a horizontal fashion. When they click on the images, they should open a locally stored PDF/PDF from site in the app itself.

The problem is that whenever I put a scrollview (horizontal or vertical), my app crashes when I try to go to the activity that contains the view.

Currently, said activity looks like this:

Full xml code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/generatieve_tros" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/botrytis" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@73c34ee[activity_kop]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
    D/ViewRootImpl@73c34ee[activity_kop]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
    D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=80
    D/ViewRootImpl@8980143[activity_tree]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
    D/ViewRootImpl@8980143[activity_tree]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
    D/ViewRootImpl@8980143[activity_tree]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
    D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 86(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 142MB/158MB, paused 153us total 9.255ms
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 31(944B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 142MB/158MB, paused 135us total
14.916ms
    I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 126MB allocation
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 142MB/158MB, paused 143us total
13.015ms
    W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 16772392 free bytes and 113MB until OOM"
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(144B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 142MB/158MB, paused 146us total 8.006ms
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 142MB/158MB, paused 152us total
13.678ms
    I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 126MB allocation
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 142MB/158MB, paused 147us total
12.795ms
    W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 16776400 free bytes and 113MB until OOM"
    D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: eu.app.app, PID: 8423
                      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 16776400 free bytes and 113MB until OOM
                          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1179)
                          at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:770)
                          at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
                          at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1640)
                          at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
                          at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                          at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                          at eu.app.app.activity_fruit.onCreate(activity_fruit.java:12)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) Application terminated.
```

Comment: You're getting an OutOfMemoryException - the images are taking up too much space in memory. Search for 'downsampling bitmaps on Android'.

Comment: Just use Glide [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load these images instead of directly putting them in xml layout

Comment: Thanks! Really great pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you are trying to load is too big and it is causing out of memory exception. Try using an image loader like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to down sample and load the image into image view like this,

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(R.drawable.image)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(100,100)/*down sample*/)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        //load the image into image view     
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I'm using `code ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_fruit1);

        Glide.with(this)

                
.load(R.drawable.kumato)

                .into(imageView); ` , but it seems to cause a fatal exception on run. Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.app.app/eu.app.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException:

Comment: Removing the code, the app works. However, I want to use your code, but I'm having trouble with the Glide.with(context) (cannot resolve context). And the Drawable resources.

Comment: you can pass the activity as the context

Answer (score 0):

`android:largeHeap="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml